# Performance issues when retrieving last value

Tags: influxdb

I have a measurement that keeps track of sensor readings for a bunch of machines.

There are something of the order of 50 different readings per machine, and there are up to 1000 machines. We have one reading every 30 seconds.

The way I store the reading is in a single measurement which has 2 tags, machine_id and analysis_id and a single value.

One of the use cases I have is to retrieve the current value for each reading for a list of machines.

When this database gets to 100 million records or something like that, which with those numbers means less than 1 day, I can no longer retrieve the last values with a query as it takes too long.

I tried the two following alternatives:

```
SELECT *
FROM analysisvalue
WHERE entity_id = '1' or entity_id = '2'
GROUP BY analysis_id, entity_id
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and:

```
SELECT last(*) AS value,
FROM analysisvalue
WHERE entity_id = '1' or entity_id = '2'
GROUP BY analysis_id, entity_id
```

both of then take a pretty long time to complete. At 100 million it's something of the order of 1 second.

The use case of retrieving the latest values is a very frequent one. I need to be able to get the "current" state of machines almost instantly.
I can work that out on the side of the app logic, by keeping track of the latest value in a separate place, but I was wondering what I could do with InfluxDB alone.

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you on?

Comment: I'm on the latest, 1.2.

Comment: Can you open up an [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new) on the InfluxDB repo for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something similar and I worked around it by creating a continuous query.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/api/continuous_queries/

Comment: I've been thinking about how to use a continuous query for that but I can't come up with a good way of doing it. Could you elaborate on how you did it?